# Openlayers 3 drawing circle

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I am using openlayers 3 and i am trying to draw a circle, but it doesn't , do i have any mistakes in the code mentioned ???

```
function DrawCircle() {
            var circleCoordinates = [3210202.3139208322, 5944966.311907868, 3075978.8922520624, 6055647.128864803];
            var circle = new ol.geom.Circle(circleCoordinates);
            var feature = new ol.Feature(circle);

            var id = guid();
            feature.featureID = id;
            feature.setProperties({
                'id': id,
                'name': typeSelect.value,
                'description': 'Some values'
            })
            source.addFeature(feature);
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the API docs here: http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html

You're passing the wrong options to the constructor.

new ol.geom.Circle(center, opt_radius, opt_layout)

Comment: opt_radius, opt_layout what values are ??